# Email not appearing in outlook client, but showing on iPhone

Tags: outlook, microsoft-office-365

My environment consists of the following:

- Users are on Office 2016 installed from Office365
- Email is handled by Office365 Cloud installation

One user is experiencing an issue whereby they will receive some messages on their iPhone (using Outlook app), but the same messages will not appear on their desktop client.

- I've checked for mail filters for the user, there are none.
- I've checked the mail transport logs. No errors with messages being sent to the recipient
- I've recreated the user profile on their laptop, pulling all mail fresh.

With all the steps above, the issue remains. Ideas are welcome for troubleshooting, as I'm baffled and can't reproduce with any other user.

Thank you